# How would this Angular 10 code be in React?

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, rxjs, axios

I have to implement a code made in angular, but in reactjs, the problem is that in reactjs I don't have some angular libraries, so I'm forced to modify code.
On the Angular side, I import to rxjs and do an http query:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public user: Observable<User>;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  refreshToken() {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${apiUrl}/users/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true })
      .pipe(map((user) => {
      this.userSubject.next(user);
      this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
      return user;
    ));
  }
  private startRefreshTokenTimer() {
    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(this.userValue.jwtToken.split('.')[1]));
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now() - (60 * 1000);
    this.refreshTokenTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshToken().subscribe(), timeout);
  }
}
```

On the react side, I also use rxjs but obviously instead of import '@angular/common/http' I am using Axios and rxjs. The rest of the class is almost the same, where I have problems is in these parts: (I am also using typescript)

```
refreshToken() {
  //HttpClient is an import of a generic requests object like {post:(url, body, conf)=>axios.post(url, body)}
  return HttpClient.post("/user/refresh-token", {}, axiosOptions).then(response => {
    ....
  });
}
...
private startRefreshTokenTimer() {
  ...
  this.refreshTokenTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshToken().subscribe(), timeout);
}
```

I am following this guide: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/25/angular-10-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens I am basically adapting that structure in React, I use this guide because it uses the same backend as me.

Comment: I am hoping you are facing issues wrt to the observable part.
In angular httpClient is an observable and for that you need `subscrible` to execute the observable, but in react you don't need that, you can just simply make it as an object method and call it directly.

Comment: that's what I thought, so I guess I can use the .then(response => {...}); But how do I mix the (response) and the .map((user)=>{});? I no longer require the rxjs library? @Vaibhav

Comment: So previously everything is observable, so your code will have to act accordingly but if are not using observable then you don't need `map` and other, `refreshToken` takes the user and returns the user, so you don't need `map` just in the `(response => {})` call the function to update the user or say user subject and call startRefreshTokenTimer` for refreshing the token.

Comment: You have clarified some things for me, thank you. but I get other doubts when making `refreshToken` return a simple User class and not using `map` and `subscribe`. It blows my mind why an infinite loop between `refreshToken()` and `startRefreshTokenTimer()` is not generated, I think the `subscribe` has to do with this. or maybe the loop is on purpose, this is very confusing. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ @Vaibhav

Comment: Okay, so use case is like, when refresh gets call it also bind the `startRefreshTokenTimer`, and it will again call the refresh to refresh the token, now `subscribe` in timeout is to trigger the refresh and making this process recursive. To achieve same save you have to do nothing but instead call the refresh once and in that response call the timer and set the timeout and call the refresh as per the timeout.

Comment: The purpose of the loop is to execute the `refreshToken` observable on specific `timeout` and to execute the observable, we will have to use the subscribe, and in a case where `refreshToken` is not observable you don't need the `subscribe` you just to execute it directly for e.g.,  - `this.refreshToken()`. I will check the code to see why `setTimeout` didn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

It's literally same

```
import axios from 'axios';

export class AuthenticationService {
  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public user: Observable<User>;

  refreshToken() {
    return from(axios.post<any>(`${apiUrl}/users/refresh-token`, {}, { withCredentials: true }))
      .pipe(map((user) => {
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
        return user;
      }));
  }

  private startRefreshTokenTimer() {
    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(this.userValue.jwtToken.split('.')[1]));
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now() - (60 * 1000);
    this.refreshTokenTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshToken().subscribe(), timeout);
  }
}
```

Upd.: keep in mind, that in React world there's no such term as `Service`. In small apps you can use state, in large ones it's better to use Redux/MobX/any other app state management library (if you've worked with ngxs/ngrx/akita, you know the concept)

Comment: in `this.userSubject.next(user);` shows me a warning `Type 'AxiosResponse<any>' has no properties in common with type 'User';`. Isn't it like `userSubject.next(user.data)` or something like that ?. another question is can I use this structure together with useContext (reducers)? @Ilya Boyko